# Radial/circle placement of meshes

Tags: unreal-4, unreal

How to place 10 static meshes in circular pattern so they are equaly aligned from the center ?

Comment: You mean by code or by hand?

Comment: I was thinking by hand, but is it possible to do it by code ?

Comment: "equally aligned from the center" -> yes

*Do you mean that their centers should be at the same radius from a given point?* -> yes

*Do you want the circle to be axis-aligned?* -> yes

Answer (score 4):

In code, this is really simple to do. The following pseudo-code  assumes that the objects' origins are in the center, but if they are not, then all you have to do is to translate the final positions to account for the objects' actual origins.

```
float offset = 0.0f;  // Allows you to offset the initial object.

const float step = 360.0f / objectCount;
for (float angle = offset; angle < 360.0f + offset; angle += step)
{
    const float radians = angle * PI / 180.0f;
    const float x = circleCenter.X + cos(radians) * circleRadius;
    const float y = circleCenter.Y + sin(radians) * circleRadius;

    object->SetPosition(Vector2(x, y))
}
```

Comment: How to translate this in blueprint ?

Comment: Translating the code above to blueprints should be fairly trivial. I have no experience with blueprints but surely you can create float variables, initialize them with values, loop with a for- or a while-loop and finally set an object's position.